# vertex index in SceneKit shader modifier?

Tags: opengl, glsl, scenekit, vertex-shader

I'm trying to implement a parametric surface in SceneKit using a shader modifier in the form of a vertex shader program in GLSL.

The problem is that there does not seem to be an input variable for the vertex index among the inputs provided by SceneKit. In OpenGL, the vertex index is provided by the gl_VertexID input.

The documentation is pretty sparse about input and output variables in shader modifiers, so I'm hoping someone can confirm that the vertex index is simply not available. In which case, I'd appreciate any suggestions for getting around this in the context of a vertex shader program in SceneKit.

Comment: I suspect SceneKit can't offer this because OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support gl_VertexID. GLES 3.0 does, but so does Metal, and I suspect if you didn't have to target old devices, you wouldn't be asking about GLSL.